# Excel INDEX and MATCH Get Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel workbook that I need some help with INDEX and MATCH or any other Formula that can get me my end result.

Here is sheet1:

```
SIT_ID      METER   SUSE_CD
10834282    DT0061      B 
10834282    AW7931      P 
21676286    CQ9635      P 
21676286    DP4838      B 
21726281    AW7880      P 
21726281    DT0032      B
```

Here is Sheet2:

```
Site ID        B    P
10834282        
21676286        
21726281
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do is on Sheet2 is put the Meter that = B for the SITEID in the column and then Put the Meter that = P in the Same row.

I have never used Index or Match and I looked it up online but I am confused and hoping someone can help me with the correct formula or point me in the right direction.

Thanks so much!

Comment: So the first row should have DT0061 under B and AW7931 under P?

Comment: @JüriRuut yes that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INDEX` first takes a range, then a row number, an optional column number (and an optional area number).

`MATCH` takes a value to lookup, an array and a mode.

In your problem you can use the following in Sheet2 cell B2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7, MATCH($A2, IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7=B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7), 0))
```

This formula is an array formula and will work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then you can fill it to the other cells.

I had to use an `IF` because there're two conditions to check.

EDIT: Use this one if your cell formats are different:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH($A2*1,IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7=B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7*1),0))
```

EDIT2: Adding trimming:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH($A2*1,IF(TRIM(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7)=TRIM(B$1),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7*1),0))
```

EDIT3: If you're using it on your full data, change the range:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH($A2*1,IF(TRIM(Sheet1!$C:$C)=TRIM(B$1),Sheet1!$A:$A*1),0))
```

Comment: @kevinc Your first table is in Sheet1 in range A1:C7, your second table is in sheet2 range A1:C4, right? Are you making sure you're using Ctrl+Shift+Enter after pasting the formula in the cell and not Enter alone?

Comment: Yes I made sure I hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter and yes that is correct

Comment: @kevinc I think I know what's the issue. Some of the `Site ID` are in number format while some are in text format. See if the amended formula works.

Comment: Yea I am still getting the N/A --- it is driving me crazy

Comment: @kevinc Uh... I don't understand why you have that error. It's a lookup error. Try removing all spaces? Spaces in the cells will cause the function to break. I can add TRIM() to the relevant parts, but it's really a data keeping issue :( I'll add it just in case.

Comment: I am not sure why but it keeps doing the N/A

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq1OREDlEWMwdFZSVHJCSlRiTDNtS1lFTHo3emtTamc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Sheet1 looks like this:

[image: tigeravatar Sheet1 data setup]

And your Sheet2 looks like this:

[image: tigeravatar Sheet2 data setup]

The formula in Sheet2 cell B2 and copied over and down to cell C4 is:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=$A2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7=B$1),),0))
```

Note that this is a regular formula, so no need for Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: I manually typed in these values and it worked... However when I copy my list get a N/A with this formula... I wonder why

Comment: Like Jerry is suggesting, that means that the formula isn't finding the data properly within Sheet1.  This is usually due to formatting issues or bad data entry.  I'd have to see your data to be able comment more specifically.

Comment: Yes I am sadly figuring this out that its formatting issues... However I have 1000+ site IDS that are like this

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq1OREDlEWMwdFZSVHJCSlRiTDNtS1lFTHo3emtTamc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

A helper column D is added to initial columns.
D2: `=$A2 & $C2`

Now it's possible to make a simple search of the concatenated SITE_ID and SUSE_CD:
H2: `=MATCH($G2&" B";$D$2:$D$8;0)`

The result would be a row number (=1 in this case) for the needed string in array `$D$2:$D$8`.

INDEX shows the value of the cell, found by counting n-th row (defined by MATCH) and m-th column (=2) in array `$A2:$A$8` from the upper left cell (A2).

Altogether: `=INDEX($A$2:$B$8;MATCH($G2&" B";$D$2:$D$8;0);2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get around with this is,
to use concatenation operator in the match function.

Don't forget to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Use below formula in column B of Sheet 2

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2&Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A&Sheet1!$C:$C,0))}
```

And the below formula in column C of Sheet 2

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2&Sheet2!$C$1,Sheet1!$A:$A&Sheet1!$C:$C,0))}
```

And then flash fill the remaining rows.

[image]