# Excel - Search Sheet 1 using a list from Sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have 2 sheets in Excel.

Sheet 1 contains a Column of Order Numbers amongst other things

Sheet 2 contains just a Column of Order Numbers.

I would like to search Sheet 1 for all of the order numbers that are contained in Sheet 2 and then either Highlight the matching order numbers or delete the entire row from Sheet 1 in which the matching order number was found.

I think this maybe possible using VLookUp?

Comment: This can be done in many ways. Put screenshot of sample data from two sheet. If you want to delete row then have to use `VBA`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without VBA:

1. use index/match or vlookup to find the the order numbers
2. filter the rows of Sheet 1 in order to see just the rows which are not found in Sheet 2 (depending on your formula, this could be Blank values, N/A, etc)
3. delete all rows where the lookup returned no match

[Excel INDEX and MATCH Get Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857548/excel-index-and-match-get-value)